# One contact with several numbers - sent messages

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, sms

I have a contact with multiple (two) mobile numbers.

How do i know to which number the sms (text message) was sent?
The system did not ask me which telephone number to use.

Is there a way to check it?

Comment: If You have iOS 8, tap on Details (upper right corner) and then "i" icon, the number should be highlighted in blue. Just guessing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*For iOS 12 and later*:

Starting at the screen with the all the messages you have sent to/received from the contact, tap the contact icon at the top of the screen (this can either be the picture you assigned for the given contact, or a gray circle with the first letter of the contact's name, if you have not assigned a contact image). After clicking this icon, a small menu bar will appear below the contact icon with three options, in gray: `audio`, `FaceTime`, and `info`; click `info`. The next screen will have similar options, but this time in blue. Once again, click `info`.

You should now be able to see the information for the given contact. Check where the phone numbers are listed – one of them should have a gray `RECENT` tag next to it. This is the number you are looking for – it denotes the phone number that you either got the most recent message from, or sent the most recent message to.

Note that if you are looking in the Contacts app, you will not see the `RECENT` tag. You must go through the Messages app in order to see this.

*For earlier versions of iOS*:

When typing in a contact name while creating a new message in the Messages app, if the contact sheet for that person has more than one number (or email addresses too) it'll display a list of all numbers. From there you can select which number you'd like to send the message to for that specific contact.

If you've already sent a message and wish to determine what number or email address you're using, simply tap on the message -> details -> the "i" icon. The contact sheet will display the currently used number/email in blue (the other numbers will be black).

Comment: You should be able to distinguish numbers (work,personal) from Messages' main view. Why should youtap on anything to figure out which phone number was used. Imagine situation when one person has four numbers, you would spend 5 minutes clicking on threads to find a correct one.

Comment: I’m using iOS 15, and neither of the two suggestion above make sense. Could you include screenshots?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

(This was done using iOS 13.5.1)

Answer (score 2):

Damian is correct above.

Hit "(i)" in the top right corner -> tap the person's contact -> look for which contact method has "RECENT" next to it. That's the one used in the thread.

Comment: Hi Justin, welcome to Stack Exchange! Your note about the "recent" text is useful, but might be better suited as an edit to Damian's post. To edit a post, just click the "Edit" link below it. Having incorporated your addition there, you may then want to delete this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS if you follow the I symbol in the upper right hand corner of the message screen it will take you to a place where the contact name is given. Click on the name âne a list of all their numbers will show up. Next to the number that is related to the message you are inquiring about will have the word "recent" posted next. Apparently recent doesn't mean it is their most recent number like I had first assumed.

Comment: Use three phone numbers! How dumb, Apple just doesn't care.