# How to find which of several numbers for the same contact I sent a message to

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, contacts

For a contact with several phone numbers, how do I find which number I sent a message to?

I am trying to find which of the contact's numbers to try next, because I'm not getting a reply.

The techniques given in these two answers no longer work, or don't work for me:

- [One contact with several numbers - sent messages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162512/one-contact-with-several-numbers-sent-messages)
- [How to find the phone number text message sent from?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7447332)

Specifically, I have tried the following:

1. view the message thread
2. tap the (i) icon top right
3. tap either the contact name or the '>' beside it

This doesn't help, because all the contact's numbers are listed in blue and none are tagged with 'Recent'.

I'm using iOS 11.2.6 on an iPhone SE.

Comment: Since you mentioned that all the contact's numbers are listed in blue, that means all the numbers are registered with iMessage. It is apparent that your this person is using iPhone for all the numbers. The numbers could be all linked to same or different Apple ID. If the numbers are all linked to the same Apple ID (the person has signed in using the same Apple ID on all the iPhone's), it is likely that the message (iMessage) is delivered to all the iPhones. If that's not the case, you can go to Messages app, type in the contact number (not the name) and send message to that number.

Comment: Well, one of the numbers is this contact's fixed line, so I would be surprised if that was registered with iMessage (but fixed lines can receive txts - mine does). I mentioned the blue colour because both the previous posts I linked to said that (in the past?) the number that a message had been sent to was shown in blue.

Comment: Certainly iMessages are shown on a blue /background/ - are you sure that phone numbers listed in blue text support iMessage? I've just checked iMessages on a green background to another contact without iMessage, and when I look at that contact's details, all their phone numbers are listed in blue.

Comment: iMessage on green background is a regular SMS. iOS uses the same Messages app to send iMessage and SMS depending on whether the receipent’s contact is registered with iMessage or not respectively. I’m not sure about whether a fixed line number can br registered with iMesage even if it can receive text.